# Removal of system apps in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

How to remove the Fonts app from Ubuntu 20.04? And also how to view package name of system apps?

Comment: WHY do that? You have a reason?

Answer (score 0):

The package name of the Fonts application is `gnome-font-viewer`. You can remove it using the command:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-font-viewer
```

In general, you can list the installed applications using:

```
apt list --installed
```

`apt list` also accepts [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) for matching package names, as can be seen in [`man apt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html):

```
list
    list is somewhat similar to dpkg-query --list in that it can display a list of packages
    satisfying certain criteria. It supports glob(7) patterns for matching package names as well
    as options to list installed (--installed), upgradeable (--upgradeable) or all available
    (--all-versions) versions.
```

So you could list all installed packages containing "font" using:

```
apt list --installed "*font*"
```

and you would find `gnome-font-viewer` among others.

Comment: The `gnome-font-viewer` package places no files in /etc, so is `purge` necessary? Would plain old `remove` accomplish the same?

Comment: @user535733 It's a habit of mine to use `purge` instead of `remove`, unless I know I want to keep the configuration files. In essence, the result is the same in this case, so it wouldn't make a difference if `remove` was used instead of `purge`.